# Neovim show "space" tabs as one character

Tags: vim, neovim

In Neovim I have these set

```
set list listchars=tab:\›\ ,trail:-,extends:>,precedes:<,eol:¬,space:·

set smarttab
set expandtab
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
```

This makes my tabs 4 spaces instead of hard tabs. Unfortunately, they end up looking like this:

```
{
····"name":·"laravel/laravel",
····"description":·"The·Laravel·Framework.",
····"keywords":·["framework",·"laravel"],
····"license":·"MIT",
····"type":·"project"
}
```

With hard tabs they'd have looked like this:

```
{
›   "name":·"laravel/laravel",
›   "description":·"The·Laravel·Framework.",
›   "keywords":·["framework",·"laravel"],
›   "license":·"MIT",
›   "type":·"project"
}
```

Is there a way to represent space tabs the way it used to do for hard tabs for me?

Comment: This isn't possible with `listchars` as far as I can see. You'll have to add a syntax highlight group or use `:match`.

Comment: No, because your tabs are being expanded to 4 spaces, and each space is displayed as a `·`. There isn't any such thing as "space tabs".

Comment: Although `listchars` aren't capable of this AFAIK, you can try plugins such as [Yggdroot/indentLine](https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine) and [nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides](https://github.com/nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides). Related : [How to add indentation guides/lines - vi.stackexchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/666/466)

Comment: Thanks guys, I wasn't looking for a solution via `listchars` per se, but a solution to it in general. That indentLine plugin looks beautiful and is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks again.